# How to connect project on GCP to Google cloud SQL(postgres)

Tags: angular, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect my angular app on GCP to cloud postgresql.However it keep returning 404.Here is my yaml code:

```
`runtime: nodejs16
instance_class: F2
env_variables: 
  BUCKET_NAME: "todomvc-bc"
  INSTANCE_UNIX_SOCKET: /cloudsql/trans-proposal-3771:us-central1:post
  DB_USER: postgres
  DB_PASS: 999999
  DB_NAME: todomvc
handlers:
- url: /
 static_files: dist/todomvc-app/index.html
  upload: dist/todomvc-app/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: dist/todomvc-app`
```

i have also got an express  .env file in my server file:

```
`  DB_USER='postgres'
DB_PASSWORD='1111'
DB_HOST='trans-proposal-37:us-central1:post\'
DB_PORT='5432'
DB_DATABASE='postgres'`
```

the proxy setting should be listening to port 5432 like this:
`{ "/api": { "target": "http://localhost:5432", "secure": false } }`

however when i deploy it to GCP i cannot reach the SQL server. Can anyone help me with this?Many thanks!!!!!

Comment: Does it work on your local environment? If so, does cloud sql proxy run in your runtime environment?

Comment: Also, where are you deploying to?

Comment: it did works on local environment, the proxy is 3800 which is my express server. i am deploying it on app engine